# Saving Data from multiple android activity to one Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Below is the code for both of my activities. By coding like this, the data get stored like this in firebase. This is a snapshot of the stored data:

[image: this is the Snap of stored data]

But I want to store data in firebase like this, I want to store them under enrollment number field like this:

[image: this is how i want data]

I want to store data from multiple activities under the same child element, like I showed in the second screenshot.

**AccountyActivity.java**

```
 private void init() {

    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);

    mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
            // location is received
            mCurrentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            lot = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
            lgt = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
            lg = Double.toString(lgt);
            lt = Double.toString(lot);
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

            UID = user.getUid();
            final DatabaseReference myRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://smartattendance-c896a.firebaseio.com/Users");

            DatabaseReference user1 = myRootRef.child(UID);
            user1.child("Longitude").setValue(lg);
            user1.child("Latitude").setValue(lt);
```

**SignUpActivity.java**

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    final DatabaseReference myRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://smartattendance-c896a.firebaseio.com/Users");
    f1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newUserName);
    f2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newPassword);
    signUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupbtn);
    signInLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signinlink);
    tnc = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.tnc);
    f3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cfmpassword);
    f4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enroll);
    signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startSignup();
            String Enrollment = f4.getText().toString();

            String email = f1.getText().toString();
            String pass = f2.getText().toString();
            DatabaseReference user = myRootRef.child(Enrollment);
            user.child("Email").setValue(email);
            user.child("Password").setValue(pass);
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can make a class for Users's value that have constructor, get setter .

Comment: Can you please tell me in more detail?

Answer (score 2):

Pass the value from one activity to another:

In the **SignupActivity**:

```
Intent i=new Intent(SignUpActivity.this,AccountyActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("id",Enrollment);
```

Then in the **AccountyActivity** do the following:

```
String id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
DatabaseReference myRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        DatabaseReference ref = myRootRef.child(id);

        Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
         childUpdates.put("Longitude", lg);
         childUpdates.put("Latitude",lt);

        ref.updateChildren(childUpdates);
```

You need to use `updateChildren` so you do not overwrite the other child nodes.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Comment: It leads to app crash , Error like -  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.webkit.SafeBrowsingResponse" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.chrome-aUzt4fYmXssoFSuxR68MlA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.chrome-aUzt4fYmXssoFSuxR68MlA==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.android.chrome-aUzt4fYmXssoFSuxR68MlA==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]

Comment: that has nothing to do with the code above, are u using webview in your app?

Comment: can i share you all the project files ? from github ? i'm using karumi:dexter and butterknife , are they webview ? are they causing problem?

Comment: i am currently working on https://github.com/dhruv850/SmartAttendanceApp.git branch name is dhruv , please look into the matter and help me , thank you

Comment: hey on which method i have to include code of accountactivity that u have mentioned above , on onCreate Method it leads to app crash.

Answer (score 0):

I have suggestion for you. You have to change a few things.
1. Make a class to write new data (Sign Up Activity)

For example class like this.

UsersInformation.java

```
package <replace with your package>;
public class UsersInformation {

private long enrollment;
private String email;
private String password;
//Maybe you want to use double, change it to double
private float latitude;
private float longitude;

public UsersInformation() {
}

public UsersInformation(long enrollment, String email, String password, float latitude, float longitude) {
    this.enrollment = enrollment;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public long getEnrollment() {
    return enrollment;
}

public void setEnrollment(long enrollment) {
    this.enrollment = enrollment;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public float getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(float latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public float getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(float longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}
}
```

SignUpActivity.java

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mRefUsers;

private UsersInformation userInfo;

private long enrollment;
private String email;
private String password;
//Maybe you want to use double, change it to double
private float latitude;
private float longitude;


private void writeNewUser(long enrollment, String email, String password, float latitude, float longitude){
userInfo = new UsersInformation(enrollment, email, password, latitude, longitude);
mRefUsers.child("Users").setValue(userInfo);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mRefUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getReference();


f1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newUserName);
f2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newPassword);
signUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupbtn);
signInLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signinlink);
tnc = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.tnc);
f3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cfmpassword);
f4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enroll);
signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        startSignup();
        enrollment = f4.getText().toString();
        email = f1.getText().toString();
        password = f2.getText().toString();
        latitude = 0.0
        longitude = 0.0

        writeNewUser(enrollment, email, password, latitude, longitude);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successfully Registered! Proceed to Main Menu...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //Proceed to Accounty Acitivty
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), AccountyActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("enrollment", enrollment);
        getContext().startActivities(new Intent[]{intent});
    }
});
```

AccountyActivity.java

```
private void init() {

mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);

mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
        // location is received
        mCurrentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
        lot = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
        lgt = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
        lg = Double.toString(lgt);
        lt = Double.toString(lot);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        UID = user.getUid();

        Intent intent = this.getIntent();
        //Store value
        float enrollment = intent.getExtras().getString("enrollment");

        final DatabaseReference myRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(enrollment);

        DatabaseReference latitudeRef = myRootRef.child("latitude");
        latitudeRef.setValue(lg);

        DatabaseReference longitudeRef = myRootRef.child("longitude");
        longitudeRef.setValue(lt);
```

Maybe a few things that you have to check.